# Opening users twitter page in the twitter app from a button press in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-twitter

I have searched quite a lot on Stack Overflow for this request however it all seems to be centred around just opening the twitter client.

I would like to click a button, open the default or used Twitter App and have it display someones profile. They then interact and click to follow if needed, however the main idea is getting the button to open the twitter app and being directed to the page in question.

I have made a simple button that goes to the persons twitter page in the browser but i would like it to be more professional.

Is this possible?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

[old but might do what you want](http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2010/06/18/using-native-twitter-app-intent-to-share-on-android/)

[another page that should help](http://labs.emich.be/2010/01/23/how-to-send-to-twitter-or-facebook-from-your-android-application/)

[last but not least](http://lisudza.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/tweeting-using-twitter-for-android-intent/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into that for me. It's ertainly helpful for being able to tweet or comment, however i'd like to view a persons twitter in the native client :)